# trouble installing pystan and fbprophet

Tags: python, python-3.x, pystan, facebook-prophet

In my ubuntu, not performing well when I am going to install **pystan** and **fbprophet**, using pip3 command. So, my system hangs badly.
I am tried so many logics still got errors, kindly please guide me how i can rectify this issues ?

Comment: Please provide more details, what errors did you get, what have you tried doing to mitigate them?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? PyStan requires a C++ compiler to be available to Python during installation and runtime and can be done by this command -

> `apt-get install build-essential`